# Credentials visible to ps (process analyzer)

Tags: password-management, process

I use the [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org) password manager on linux. I can use it to script shell commands that involve credentials without those creds showing up in my command-line history, e.g.

```
foo-cli --password=$(pass show foo)
```

The actual password won't show up in command-line history, but it *will* show up in a process analyzer like `ps`, if one happens to be running at the same time the command is executed.

```
ps a | grep foo-cli
14099 pts/3    S+     0:00 foo-cli my-cleartext-password
```

How exploitable is this? Should I consider such scripting totally unsafe even on a personal machine? Are there known attacks involving someone listening/analyzing processes?

Comment: How exploitable it is depends on your threat model. Yes, scripting that exposes sensitive data in `argv` is unsafe if you do not trust every other process running as any user. And yes, there are known attacks that involve information leakage in `/proc`.

Comment: Commands that take passwords as CLI arguments are bad form anyway.  Using environment or stdin or a temporary descriptor are better if you have to do this at all.